# How to trigger JavaScript when a counter reaches a specific number?

Tags: javascript

I want to trigger a JavaScript when a counter  reaches a specific number, such as 10.
How do I do this?

```
<button onclick="stepupfunction()"> PRESS ME </button>
<script>
     document.addListener('onLoad', function documentLoaded(e) {
        document.getElementById("score").value = store.get('putAKeyHere') || 0;
    })
    function stepupfunction() {
        document.getElementById("score").stepUp(1);
        store.set('putAKeyHere',document.getElementById("score").value)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi! Can you give a bit more context and add some code as an example of what's currently broken?

Comment: So a button raises 1 value in an input when it's clicked, the problem is, How do I make when button pressed 10 times it activates a javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work:

```
function stepupfunction() {
    var num = document.getElementById("score");
    num.stepUp(1);
    store.set('putAKeyHere', num.value);
    if (num.value >= 10) {
          // DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay - care to give any more details?  What appears in the console?

Comment: There's no change at all. I pressed the button 160 times and nothing... `<script>
document.addListener('onLoad', function documentLoaded(e) {
        document.getElementById("score").value = store.get('putAKeyHere') || 0;
    })
function stepupfunction() {
    var num = document.getElementById("score");
    num.stepUp(1);
    store.set('putAKeyHere', num.value);
    if (num.value >= 160) {
          document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "Whoa, You got better energy then 40% people in this world";
    }
}
</script>`

Comment: I tested that code and it works for me in Chrome 46.0.2490.80 m.  Have you defined `store`?  What have you put in the `if` code block?  If you replace the comment with an `alert`, are you saying the alert doesn't fire?

Comment: I made the javascript to change an `innerHTML` in a `<p>`. However I tried the javascript to do something else and NOTHING!

Comment: Right, well `document.addListener` isn't a valid function.  What you want is  `document.addEventListener`.  And the first parameter shouldn't be `onLoad` but just `load`.  And it's best to attach that event to the `window` object, not the `document` object.  Of course, why that bit of your code wasn't working was a different question :) !

Comment: I tried a series of code, and then I finally found the correct one. Thanks!